# On the existence of functions with a particular convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, integration, examples-counterexamples

Is the following scenario possible? Provide an example or argue why not.

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be measurable non-negative functions on $[0,1]$ converging to $f(x)$ pointwise Lebesgue-almsot everywhere on $[0,1]$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n =2$ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f =1$.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to ask? If $\int_0^1 f_n=1$ then the sequence $\{\int_0^1 f_n\}$ is constant and its limit is $1$.

Comment: I have now fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the functions from the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Discussion_of_the_assumptions) and shift them up by $1$. More precisely, let $f \equiv 1$ and
$$
  f_n = f+n\cdot1_{\left(0,\frac1n\right]}
$$

Comment: I fixed it. Apologies